# Circuit Diagram Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I solved a problem in which I was supposed to find the current over the ammeter. The answer is 12 because the total voltage over the circuit is given as 128 V. However, I do not understand why we don't sum up the current from the upper branch and the current from the lower branch to calculate the current over the ammeter. Can someone explain this please.

[image]

[image: here is the solution]

Comment: Please consider writing descriptive question titles with appropriate punctuation, grammar, and formatting. See this meta post: [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413).

Comment: Is the upper left resistor 20 or 2 ohms?

Comment: @BobD its 20 ohms

Answer (score 1):

> However, I do not understand why we don't sum up the current from the
>   upper branch and the current from the lower branch to calculate the
>   current over the ammeter.

There isn't an upper branch current and a lower branch current in this circuit *because the ammeter is itself a path for current*.

That is, the current $I_{20}$ through the $20\Omega$ resistor will 'split' at the junction of the ammeter and $3\Omega$ resistor.  Some of $I_{20}$ will be through the ammeter and the remainder will be through the $3\Omega$ resistor.  So it isn't clear what you mean by "current from the upper branch".

The key to solving this circuit is to understand that the ideal ammeter has zero volts across and so the two resistors to the left of the ammeter are parallel connected and the two resistor to the right of the ammeter are parallel connected.

Since parallel connected circuit elements have identical voltage across, solving for the current through the ammeter is quite straightforward.

---

RE the second diagram:

Under the assumption that the current $i$ is the current entering the network from the left, the values given don't make any sense.

Applying [current division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider), the current (to the right) through the $20\Omega$ resistor is $\frac{1}{5}i$ (and of course, the remaining $\frac{4}{5}i$ is through the $5\Omega$ resistor)

*But*, since the current leaving the network must equal the current entering the network, current division once again tells you that the current (to the right) through the $3\Omega$ resistor is $\frac{4}{5}i$.

This is *all* you need to find the current though the ammeter.  Simply apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law_(KCL)) at the junction of the upper resistors and the ammeter.

Comment: Is that a 2 ohm resistor or a 20 ohm resistor?

Comment: But current is q/t so my question is why do we subtract to find the current? For example, to calculate the current in a discharge tube we would sum up movement of charges even though they are in opposite directions .@AlfredCentauri

Comment: @ten1o, I confess that I don't see the connection between "current is q/t" and "why do we subtract...".  The logic eludes me.  Are you familiar with Kirchhoff's current law?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri added an image of the solution. The ammeter measures 3i. But according to the current formula, we would sum up to find (17/5)i

Comment: @ten1o, if you have two charge carriers in some region, one positive and one negative, and these charge carriers are moving in opposite directions, then you *add* their contributions to the electric current since 'negative charge moving leftward is equivalent to positive charge moving rightward'.  But this is a circuit problem and, in the *circuit* context, there is just *electric current*.

Comment: @ten1o, what is the current $i$?  Is it the current entering the network from the left?